# How to access public methods without initialization

Tags: java, android, android-library

I am trying to create a simple library in which I want to define my class similar to Glide. So that I can call it with `MyAnimation.with(context)`, but no matter if I define it `abstract`, `final`, or Singleton, I cannot do that. I do have to make an instance to access its public method `with(Context context)`, which is written as follows:

```
/**
 * initializes context for the current instance
 * @param context context to be used for {@link ConstraintSet}
 * @return an instance of {@link MyAnimation}
 */
public MyAnimation with(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
    mConstraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
    return this;
}
```

As you see, `with()` returns an instance of the class and then I have another public method `from(@LayouRes int res)` which takes a layout and returns `this` again.

```
/**
 *
 * @param secondKeyframe This is the layout from which constraints will be picked
 * @return An instance of this class
 * @throws IllegalStateException Throws exception if context has not been initialized
 */
public MyAnimation from(@LayoutRes int secondKeyframe, Transition customTransition) throws IllegalStateException {
    if(mContext == null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Context not initalized. Please call with(Context) first");
    }
    mTransition = customTransition;
    mConstraintSet.clone(mContext, secondKeyframe);
    return this;
}
```

Finally, there is a method `animate(ViewGroup view)` that performs a simple animation on the `ViewGroup`. Any ideas how I can achieve that?

```
   /**
     * Applies animation after applying new {@link ConstraintSet}
     * @param view The ViewGroup on which the animation will be performed
     */
    public  void animate(ViewGroup view) {
        mConstraintSet.applyTo((ConstraintLayout) view);
        mLayout = (ConstraintLayout) view;
        if(mTransition != null) {
            TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(mLayout, mTransition);
        }
        else {
            TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(mLayout);
        }

    }
```

Please, I really want to call my library like Glide (:D)

Answer (score 3):

You need to make these methods `static`. Static methods don't need am instance of class to be invoked. They are just *class members*, not *instance members*.

Comment: Thanks, but then I can't work context, I cannot return `this`, and Android complains about defining context as static.

Comment: @JasonStack You can't return 'this' as there is no instance to be returned with 'this' keyword (making method 'static' means that you don't want to connect it with any instance). Think a bit about what you really need be done within that method as returning instance is definitely not what you want from static method :-) maybe you don't need to return anything and this method will provide any  actions needed to be done with the passed parameter within its body and that's all.

Answer (score 2):

You need to to make your methods static:

```
   public class MyGlide{

    public static MyAnimation with(Context context) {
       //do something
    };
}
```

So when you call it in another activity/class you have

```
MyGlide.with(CurrentContext);
```

Comment: There's no such thing as `this` in a static context.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @Przemysław Moskal ,

1. If you want to access a method like `Class.method()` then that `method` should be `static`.
2. I guess you don't need to return `this` because you can access it with `MyAnimation.xxx` from the place where you are calling the methods - `from()` or `with()`.
3. Also, you can't access `non-static` variables from a `static` method; so, make `mContext, mConstraintSet, mTransition` etc. `static`.

Let me know if you get any more errors.

Answer (score 1):

Since, `MyAnimation` is a class defined by you and when you wrote

```
MyAnimation.with(context)
```

It means `with()` should be defined as `static` method, which tell it has class level association not with instance.

You need to also understand that, using `this` keyword is actually means current instance of this class. Now, this will contradict with above statement. You **can't** declare method as `static` and `return this` at the same time.

As you referred `Singleton` in your question, so I am assuming you are trying to `return` an instance of `MyAnimation`. So, if you need new instance in every invocation, then just change

```
return this;
```

to

```
return new MyAnimation();
```